# How to store pyc files with setuptools3 in bitbake recipe in the same way setuptools does?

Tags: python, setuptools, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I added the python-helloworld from https://github.com/yoctocookbook/meta-custom/tree/master/recipes-python/python-helloworld to my yocto build, which works fine. The files get precompiled and are copied to the image:

```
ls /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/helloworld
__init__.py   __init__.pyc  main.py       main.pyc
```

I need to use python3. Changing `inherit setuptools` to `inherit setuptools3` in the recipe adds python 3.7 instead 2.7 to my image and the script works, but the precompiled files are now in the subfolder `__pycache__` with an extension to their name:

```
ls /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/helloworld/__pycache__/
__init__.cpython-37.pyc  main.cpython-37.pyc
```

**I want to remove the .py source code files from the target build.**
With `setuptools` I can delete the .py files and the script works fine using the .pyc files. With `setuptools3`, python3 raises a `ModuleNotFoundError` after deleting the .py files.

Moving and renaming (like `__pycache__/main.cpython-37.pyc` to `main.pyc`) it works again.

What is the correct way to tell `setuptools3` to create the precompiles .pyc files in the same way as `setuptools` does to avoid this moving and renaming?

Comment: read through https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/ you seem to be relying on a legacy behaviour see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#case-4-legacy-pyc-files-and-source-less-imports but case 3 is normal behavior https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#case-3-pycache-foo-magic-pyc-with-no-source

Comment: This answers my question how to get setuptools3 to create these .pyc files: It should not be possible because having .pyc files without source works, but is legacy and thus should be avoided.
Can you please post this as an answer instead of a comment? I would like to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading through [pep-3147](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147) you seem to be relying on a legacy [case 4](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#case-4-legacy-pyc-files-and-source-less-imports) behavior but [case 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#case-3-pycache-foo-magic-pyc-with-no-source) is normal behavior, I would suggest to not rely on legacy behavior as it is supposed to go away.